# Storing a hashed value of a string in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project that has to have authentication (user name/pass)

It also connects to a database so i figured i would store the user name and password there but it seems like not such a good idea to have passwords as just a text field in a table sitting on the db.
I am using mysql database.

my table in DB:

```
                    +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
                    | Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
                    +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
                    | username   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
                    | password   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | email      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | cfmpwd     | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | firstname  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | lastname   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | identifier | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | company    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | address    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | address1   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | city       | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | state      | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | zip        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                      country    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | mobno      | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    | telno      | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                      fax        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
                    +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+------
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a GUID for a password field? Did you mean a hash?

Comment: Do you know what GUID is? did you mean hash value?

Comment: yeah hash....becoz if i use string then i can see the password in database

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hashing method you want to use, the only change would be to extend the `password` length from 15 (as it is now) to e.g. 100:

```
ALTER TABLE  `your_table` CHANGE  `password`  `password` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL
```

If now you store your passwords as plain texts, you would also need to run a script that will hash every password and save the changes in your database.

Comment: Then your password field is probably not really varchar(15) like you say in your question.

Comment: @matino: what script i have to add and how? where to save that script?